# Titanium : how to make a default "defaultImage" for all elements?

Tags: imageview, titanium, default, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

Is it possible to make a default "defaultImage" that will be used for all elements in my app (imageViews, coverflow, etc.) ? It will be great, instead of put "defaultImage" everywhere...

I've replaced the image called "photoDefault.png" in sdk_VERSION/iphone/modules/ui/, but I don't think it's the best trick...

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the Alloy framework you can do it this way, just define a global View style in your app.tss:

```
"ImageView" : {
   defaultImage : 'yourDefaultImage.png'
}
```

All image views will have this as there default background image now, unless you override it in code.

If you don't want to use alloy, just do this instead:

```
Titanium.UI.createImageView = Ti.UI.createImageView = function(attributes) {
    attributes.defaultImage = 'yourDefaultImage.png';
    var self = Titanium.UI.createImageView(attributes);    
    return self;
}
```

This just reassigns the Titanium namespace to a different function, that wraps the `createImageView` with your custom default image.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) , but I don't use Alloy, and your method is using the backgroundImage and not the defaultImage parameter.

Comment: Well, use alloy :) I updated the answer for default images, and added a way to do it without alloy